# How can I influence the direct buffer memory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I have a problem, my apps are deployed in containers and I permanent and stable catch out of memory.

I tried to restrict buffer memory with -xx:MaxDirectMemorySize then I caught another out of memory with direct buffer memory as a result. I got into a vicious circle and maybe does someone know decision?
Apps don't use DirectByteBuffer, but memory is growing. I use Spring Boot 2.3.12.

Comment: A broad answer to the broad question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
Please provide more details about your environment: linux kernel version, linux distributive version, java version and provider, memory allocation manager (if it has been changed), containerization tools version.

My suggestion is to use async-profiler to verify memory leak call stack frames https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler.
Then try to change a default memory allocator akka malloc. I highly recommend it to use this one https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc, please take a look at this implementation.